# How to generate n points on a circumference and connect all of them while having constraints on the image size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have to generate a circle that has n points on the circumference that have to be connected with all possible cords. I drew the required picture using Geogebra and tried exporting it as a normal `png`. However the quality of the png file was not good enough, thus I decided to export the image as an eps file. If I include the `eps` in my file the picture is displayed, but as I resize it, the lines become either too wide or, the indices of the points become so small that the picture is not useful. So I tried to export the image in terms of PGF/TikZ code. But I had the same problem. I cannot predict how big the image will be, thus after exporting I have to resize it. So my question is what should I do ? Is there an easier way to draw such circle? What can I do about the image size, so I will not need to resize the image every time ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just with the help of TikZ it is perfectly possible to do such a job. Here is indeed a possible solution that allows you to

1. easily set the number of points on the circle;
2. set the circle radius;
3. decide the position of the picture in terms of coordinates
4. eventually position labels.

The first three things are did by one command: `\drawconnectvertices` while to add labels one should use `\drawconnectverticeslabelled`.

Here is the code (revised thanks to Brent suggestion in the comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric} % required for the polygon shape

\def\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=#1, circle radius=#2] at (#3);{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\vertices{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\circleradius{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
\draw[blue] (#3) circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
\foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
    \node[draw,circle, inner sep=1pt,blue, fill=blue] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
}

\foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}{
            \draw[ultra thin, red] (vertex set.corner \x)--(vertex set.corner \y);
    }
}
}

\def\drawconnectverticeslabelled[num vertex=#1, circle radius=#2, shift angle=#3] at (#4);{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\vertices{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\circleradius{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
\draw[blue] (#4) circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
\foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
    \node[draw,circle, inner sep=1pt,blue, fill=blue] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
    \pgfmathparse{#3-360*(\x-1)/ \vertices}
    \node at ($(vertex set)+(\pgfmathresult:\halfcircleradius)$)[label={[font=\small]\pgfmathresult:$\x$}]{};
}

\foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}{
            \draw[ultra thin, red] (vertex set.corner \x)--(vertex set.corner \y);
    }
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawconnectverticeslabelled[num vertex=6, circle radius=3, shift angle=0] at (0,0.75);
\drawconnectverticeslabelled[num vertex=4, circle radius=2, shift angle=45] at (4,0.75);
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=8, circle radius=3] at (8,0.75);
\drawconnectverticeslabelled[num vertex=15, circle radius=6, shift angle=90] at (4,-5);
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=30, circle radius=8] at (4,-13.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

One remark on `\drawconnectverticeslabelled`: as it is possible to see from the example, the order of the labels could be changed according to the `shift angle`.

---

After having seen [TeX Parameter Processing imitating key-value pairs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88325/tex-parameter-processing-imitating-key-value-pairs), here is a complete TikZ-based solution.

I've defined `\drawconnectvertices` as an alias of `\node` and now the parameters and the type of drawing are set up with `pgfkeys`:

- parameters:

  1. `num vertex`;
  2. `circle radius`;
  3. `shift angle`;
  4. `at pos` *(new)*: provides the coordinates in which the node is positioned;
- type of drawing:

  1. `circumference with points`;
  2. `circumference with points labelled`.

Notice that the parameters should *always* be declared before the type of drawing.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[height=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric} % required for the polygon shape

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
     num vertex/.initial=6,
     num vertex/.get=\vertices,
     num vertex/.store in=\vertices,
     circle radius/.initial=3,
     circle radius/.get=\circleradius,
     circle radius/.store in=\circleradius,
     shift angle/.initial=0,
     shift angle/.get=\shiftangle,
     shift angle/.store in=\shiftangle, 
     at pos/.initial={(0,0)},
     at pos/.get=\position,
     at pos/.store in=\position,
}

% that's just an alias for \node
\makeatletter
\def\drawconnectvertices{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/tikz/circumference with points/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
        \draw[blue] \position circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
            \node[draw,circle, inner sep=1pt,blue, fill=blue] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
        }

        \foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
            \foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}{
                    \draw[ultra thin, red] (vertex set.corner \x)--(vertex set.corner \y);
            }
        }
    }
}   

\pgfkeys{/tikz/circumference with points labelled/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
        \draw[blue] \position circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
            \node[draw,circle, inner sep=1pt,blue, fill=blue] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
            \pgfmathparse{\shiftangle-360*(\x-1)/ \vertices}
            \node at ($(vertex set)+(\pgfmathresult:\halfcircleradius)$)[label={[font=\small]\pgfmathresult:$\x$}]{};
        }

        \foreach \x in {1,...,\vertices}{
            \foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}{
                    \draw[ultra thin, red] (vertex set.corner \x)--(vertex set.corner \y);
            }
        }
    }
}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawconnectvertices[at pos={(0,0.75)}, circumference with points labelled] {};
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=4, 
    circle radius=2,
    at pos={(4,0.75)},
    shift angle=45,circumference with points labelled] {};
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=8,
    at pos={(8,0.75)},
    circumference with points] {};
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=15,
    circle radius=6, 
    shift angle=90,
    at pos={(4,-5)},
    circumference with points labelled] {};
\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=30,
    circle radius=8,
    at pos={(4,-13.5)}, 
    circumference with points] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

provides the same result displayed above.

Comment: Beautiful. Just one question: wouldn't `\foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}{` be sufficient?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have just two more questions connected to your code. When I try to insert the number of vertices to be 2, I get the following error: ! Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate `1/0.0', but I cannot divid
e any number by zero. What should I do in order to plot a circle with 2 points ? And secondly is there any way to label the points created  ?

Comment: @user23707 : Hmm, I think TikZ may not be quite up to making a two-sided polygon...

Comment: @user23707: Brent made the point; indeed, in my solution I used the polygon shape (it helps cause all nodes are labelled), thus when you set up `num vertex=2` an error arises. For what concern the labels: do you need arbitrary labels of a solution like [My polygon graph ends up “wonky” and I don't know why](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85180/my-polygon-graph-ends-up-wonky-and-i-dont-know-why/85186#85186) is good?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: yes, `\foreach \y in {\x,...,\vertices}` is sufficient. Thanks for the remark `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I am thoroughly confused...  This might warrant a separate question, but how does the parameter processing work here? First, The first parameter to `\drawconnectvertices` is not really optional. Second, when I read the invocation of `\drawconnectvertices[num vertex=4, circle radius=2]`, I see `#1` is `num vertex=4, circle radius=2`, so the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\vertices{#1}` should have failed. I really did not know that TeX was _that_ flexible in how you can define macros.  Let me know if I should post a separate question.

Comment: @PeterGrill: well, unfortunately I don't have an answer because I realized this behaviour almost by chance (I tried and it worked) while attempting to emulate the usual key usage. Notice that you will get errors if you missed a blank space, for example `num vertex =4`, so from the user point of view is much more clear to write, but not so flexible IMHO. But I think a question to our gurus to clarify the behaviour is more than welcome. `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Question posted: [TeX Parameter Processing imitating key-value pairs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88325/tex-parameter-processing-imitating-key-value-pairs).

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've seen the question and both answers; especially egreg's answer is very clear and now I've understood the behaviour.

Comment: Can I change style thin by another style. I want thicker.

Comment: @minthao_2011: yes, use the key `thick` or `very thick` or `ultra thick`.

Comment: `thick` or `very thick` not good. How another way? How can I use, E.g, linewidth=0.2pt ?

Comment: @minthao_2011: In that case you may want to try some custom `linewidth` indeed: the option is almost as you said, `line width=<x>pt`.

Answer (score 15):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
 \psdots[dotscale=2](1;\INode)
 \multido{\iA=0+1}{\INode}{%
   \multido{\iB=\iA+1}{\numexpr\INode-\iA+1\relax}{% 
     \psline[linecolor=blue!50](1;\iA)(1;\iB)}}}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2,linewidth=0.2pt}
\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=4] \qquad \PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=8]

\bigskip
\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=12]\qquad \PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

if you want only the connections on the circle use

```
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
 \psdots[dotscale=2](1;\INode)
 \multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{\numexpr\INode+1}{% 
     \psline[linecolor=blue!50](1;\iA)(1;\iB)}}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I draw a circumscribed circle?

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the dimensions in the `Geogebra to PGF export` window before pressing the `Generate PGF/TikZ` button.  Set `xMin`, `xMax`, `yMin`, and `yMax` (the way you want) to set a selection area which includes the graphics you created in GeoGebra.  (In this case, it is your circle.)