# How to generate n points over a circumference and choose label and color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, labels, circles

I would like to place n points over a
circumference
like Figure 3 of this [file](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=bir%C3%B2+howard+keller+stanley+depth+and+partitions&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.142.4539%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=0_8IUcq8MMjAswb7pYCgAg&usg=AFQjCNEFgdpuNytEYuj__Kl5bT6nmd-Lpg).
I'd choose the label to be assigned to each vertex and color and I'd like to have the code in TikZ-pgf.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can insert a link by using `[description](actual URL)`. Happy TeXing!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What causes you problems? Is it the circle or labels that troubles you the most?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a possible solution mainly based on [How to generate n points on a circumference and connect all of them while having constraints on the image size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88312/13304)

The adaptation from that code concerns how the labels and the colors are customized: I developed two ways basically

- `circumference with labels` which allows to customize both; they should be inserted as in a foreach loop (because they are *actually* used in a foreach loop): `label/color` (example: `1/red,2/blue`); notice that the number of pairs `label/color` should be the same of `num vertex`;
- `circumference with labels in order` which inserts the labels in clockwise order and just allows to select colors.

In addition to the keys coming from the other answer, there is one more: `vertex radius`; it allows to increase or reduce the radius of the circle representing the vertex (default value to `1.5pt`).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric} % required for the polygon shape

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
     num vertex/.initial=4,
     num vertex/.get=\vertices,
     num vertex/.store in=\vertices,
     circle radius/.initial=3,
     circle radius/.get=\circleradius,
     circle radius/.store in=\circleradius,
     shift angle/.initial=0,
     shift angle/.get=\shiftangle,
     shift angle/.store in=\shiftangle, 
     at pos/.initial={(0,0)},
     at pos/.get=\position,
     at pos/.store in=\position,
     vertex radius/.initial=1.5pt,
     vertex radius/.get=\vertexradius,
     vertex radius/.store in=\vertexradius,
}

% that's just an alias for \node
\makeatletter
\def\drawvertices{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
\makeatother   

\pgfkeys{/tikz/circumference with labels/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
        \draw \position circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
        \foreach \textlabel/\circlecolor [count=\x] in {#1}{
            \node[draw,circle, inner sep=\vertexradius,black, fill=\circlecolor] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
            \pgfmathparse{\shiftangle-360*(\x-1)/ \vertices}
            \node at ($(vertex set)+(\pgfmathresult:\halfcircleradius)$)[label={[font=\small]\pgfmathresult:$\textlabel$}]{};
        }
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/circumference with labels in order/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halfcircleradius{\circleradius/2}
        \draw \position circle (\halfcircleradius cm) node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\vertices, minimum size=\circleradius cm, draw=none, name={vertex set}] {};
        \foreach \circlecolor [count=\x] in {#1}{
            \node[draw,circle, inner sep=\vertexradius,black, fill=\circlecolor] at (vertex set.corner \x) {};
            \pgfmathparse{\shiftangle-360*(\x-1)/ \vertices}
            \node at ($(vertex set)+(\pgfmathresult:\halfcircleradius)$)[label={[font=\small]\pgfmathresult:$\x$}]{};
        }
    }
}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawvertices[at pos={(0,0.75)}, shift angle=45,circumference with labels={2/red,3/blue,1/blue,4/red}] {};

\drawvertices[at pos={(0,-5)}, shift angle=45,circumference with labels in order={red,blue,blue,red}] {};

\drawvertices[num vertex=6, 
    circle radius=4,
    at pos={(5,0.75)},
    circumference with labels={
    1/white,4/green,5/blue,2/red,3/red,6/white
    }] {};

\drawvertices[num vertex=6, 
    circle radius=4,
    at pos={(5,-5)},
    circumference with labels in order={
    white,green,blue,red,red,white
    }] {};

\drawvertices[num vertex=19, 
    circle radius=6,
    vertex radius=3pt,
    shift angle=90,
    at pos={(2.5,-12)},
    circumference with labels in order={
    white,white,white,green,blue,red,red,red,red,
    orange,orange,orange,violet,violet,violet,violet,violet,white,white 
    }] {};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: If I only want `\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawvertices[num vertex=10, 
    circle radius=4,
    at pos={(5,-5)},
    circumference with labels in order={
    red,blue,red,blue,red,blue,red,blue,red,blue
    }] {};
\end{tikzpicture}`
How can I repair your code before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: and how can the number couterclockwise?

Comment: How can I set in order clockwise `labels={
   1/red, 3/red,5/red,7/red,9/red,2/blue,4/blue,6/blue,8/blue,10/blue
    }`?

Answer (score 15):

And a poor man's solution if compared to Claudio's answer :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\numofpoints{19}
\def\circpatt{{1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,3}} % 1 filled 0 empty
\def\labelpatt{{1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14,5,15,6,16,7,17,8,18,9,19,10}}

\node[circle,draw,minimum width=4cm] (bigc) {};
\foreach \x in {0,...,\numexpr\numofpoints-1\relax}
{
\pgfmathparse{\circpatt[\x]}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax\def\mycolor{black}\else\def\mycolor{white}\fi
\node[circle,inner sep=3pt,draw,fill=\mycolor] (n-\x) at (bigc.360/\numofpoints*\x+90) {};
\node (l-\x) at (360/\numofpoints*\x+90:2.5cm)  {\pgfmathparse{\labelpatt[\x]}$\pgfmathresult$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]