# Constructing a figure showing a ring of connected nodes using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to reproduce this figure (see below) with 7 nodes and 8 nodes, but since I've never constructed a figure in LaTeX so I'm clueless.

[image]

Comment: Hey, and welcome to tex.stackexchange. Could you post a screenshot instead of the link? It is not so clear what you're looking for, as the link points to google books

Comment: Please insert the figure here. We don't follow external links. For example, I got this after following your link: "You have either reached a page that is unavailable for viewing or ...".

Comment: ok, no problem.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Usually you should show us what coding you have tried so far.  The [documentation of tikz / pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) contains several examples close to your problem.  So I would suggest you try to follow those, and then ask us again when you run into problems.

Comment: @JouleV attached

Comment: One purpose of stackexchange is to create a knowledge data base that will be useful for others. This is why it is always appreciated if your question is posed in a way that will render it easy to find for people with similar issues and easy to answer. I'm suggesting and edit for your question that will make sure this is fulfilled. For your next question you can try and pose more clear question yourself.

Comment: Please, see [How to generate n points over a circumference and choose label and color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96009/13304) and [How to generate n points on a circumference and connect all of them while having constraints on the image size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88308/13304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one out of a million ways to do this. You can use polar coordinates. This is the figure you provided, your task now is to reduce the number of edges in each polygon, i.e. do some changes in `\foreach` loop. This only requires very simple maths, right?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
    \draw (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
}
\foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
}
\foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
    \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
    \draw (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
    \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit 1:

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
        \draw (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
    }
    \foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
        \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
    }
    \foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
        \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
    }
    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
    \foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
        \draw (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
        \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1mm);
    }
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{my:figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this variant of the many answers provided. as I want this to be a figure, I want it to be centralised, how can I do this?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I put \[ and \] before \begin{tikzpicture} and after \end{tikzpicture} and it worked but let me try what you suggested

Comment: this completely is the opposite what I wanted! but thanks for suggesting. if you see what I did you will understand

Comment: @Math Ok, you should add what you want to the question, and I will have a look at it!

Comment: Mhm, but this not what I want. what I want is the image to be central

Comment: and also if I want to add a label(figure 1.1) beneath the image, what must I add?

Comment: I shall take note :)

Comment: @Math I edited my question.

Comment: Yup however how I do remove the extra text?

Comment: and sorry for being picky, is there a way to make the lines on the nodes a tad thicker?

Comment: @Math Well, delete the `lipsum[]`s and add your own :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90320/discussion-between-joulev-and-math).

Answer (score 2):

Using Ti*k*Z library `shapes`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{whitecirc/.style={fill=white,draw=black,thick},
blackcirc/.style={draw=black,thick}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\ptsize{1.5pt}   
    \node[draw,regular polygon,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=3cm,regular polygon sides=7](P) {};
    \foreach \t in {1,3,5,7}{
    \fill[whitecirc] (P.corner \t) circle (\ptsize);}
    \foreach \t in {2,4,6}{
    \fill[blackcirc] (P.corner \t) circle (\ptsize);}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node[draw,regular polygon,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=3cm,regular polygon sides=8](P) {};
    \foreach \t in {1,2,...,8}{
    \fill[blackcirc] (P.corner \t) circle (\ptsize);}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot, thank you for (+1). Your suggestion is cool.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %draw 8 nodes with alternating colors
    \foreach[count=\i] \fillc in {black,white,black,white,black,white,black,white} {
            \draw[shorten <=2mm,shorten >=2mm] (\i/8*360:2)-- ({(\i-1)/8*360}:2);
            \node[minimum size=4mm,inner sep=0,circle,draw,fill=\fillc] (point\i) at ({\i/8*360}:2) {};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %draw 7 nodes, all black
    \foreach[count=\i] \fillc in {black,black,black,black,black,black,black} {
            \draw[shorten <=2mm,shorten >=2mm] (\i/7*360:2)-- ({(\i-1)/7*360}:2);
            \node[minimum size=4mm,inner sep=0,circle,draw,fill=\fillc] (point\i) at ({\i/7*360}:2) {};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Maybe a simple `\ifodd` is a more straightforward way to achieve the alternation. Of course, your way is more general in that you can have arbitrary patterns.